# replace Markdown link with the bare url in special cases

Tags: regex

My dataset has an attribute with a link in Markdown format.

For example:

`[stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)`
`[GitHub](https://www.github.com)`
`[See](http://www.microsoft.com)`
`[More info](http://www.apple.com)`
`[Even more info](http://www.google.com)`

For the last three rows, I want to change the value of the attribute into the url between the brackets. So the resulting dataset should look like:

`[stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)`
  `[GitHub](https://www.github.com)`
  `http://www.microsoft.com`
  `http://www.apple.com`
  `http://www.google.com`

How do I achieve this with a regular expression?

I came up with this:

Search for: `^\[See\]\((.*?)\)$`
Replace with: `\1`

That works fine for the first three rows, but leaves the last two unchanged of course. I can't seem to figure out how to do what I want with one single regular expression. Any suggestions?

Comment: This can be fuzzy if you have more then these three sample strings. What's your host programming language or tool you use to run your regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\[(See|More info|Even more info)\]\((.*?)\)$
```

You need an `alternation` between the 3 versions of text, then the group to replace is now `\2`. The parentheses are a capture group, but the pipe `|` chooses from among values.

Comment: Side note: it's also possible to turn the first group into a non-capturing group `(?:See|More info|Even more info)` that way you can leave the replacement string as-is

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine supports positive look behinds you can try a more generic approach by forcing the regex tho have two preceding lines:

```
(?<=\n.+\n)\[(.*)\]\((.*?)\)$
```

and replace with `$2` respectively `\2`